# Is there a .net implementation for openthread

Tags: openthread

I have been working to connect to a device to a dongle using OpenThread.

I am looking for a .Net Implementation of Openthread.
There is a Zigbee implementaion for .net called ZigbeeNet.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [ZigbeeNet](https://github.com/zigbeenet/ZigbeeNet) it appears to be a library to interface with Zigbee device over a COM port, so I'm assuming you're also targeting .Net on Windows. The equivalent would be a [Network Co-Processor](https://openthread.io/platforms#network-co-processor-ncp) host implementation in OpenThread terminology and unfortunately there isn't a direct .Net implementation. Microsoft implemented a [Windows 10 NCP driver](https://openthread.io/platforms/windows10) which would have been a good starting point, but unfortunately they've dropped support. It still may work but YMMV.

It is possible to run the UNIX host [wpantund](https://github.com/openthread/wpantund) in a VirtualBox VM and run your .Net application in the guest.